# If I lose weight, will my voice be a little higher pitched?

Tags: voice, physiology

For instance my weight is 78 kilograms, and when I speak naturally, its around about 80 to 100 Hz in average… If I lose 10 kilograms and so I weigh 68 kilograms, will my natural speaking voice be a little higher-pitched due to the skin of my vocal cords ? Or will it change absolutely nothing ?

Comment: For what it's worth, I once gained weight, and it seemed to me my voice was a bit fuller, but not perceptibly lower.

Comment: I find it easier to sing higher when I lose weight, but that’s just anecdotal

Answer (score 3):

<sub>Disclaimer: I'm not an expert on vocal anatomy, nor am I a doctor or medical practitioner. **This isn't medical advice**, and don't treat it as such.</sub>

---

For the most part, **I would expect the answer to this to be "no"**. From my understanding, physically smaller people have higher voices not because of their total mass, but because during the growing process their vocal cords develop(ed) with less *length*. So I would not expect significant personal weight loss to correspond to a higher speaking voice in terms of frequency.

However, I won't rule out the possibility that someone's voice might be *perceived* as higher! In particular, there are a lot of factors that shape the tone of the voice, one of which is various resonant spaces in the vocal anatomy. With a reduction in physical size, those resonant spaces may change in ways that could lead to the voice sounding different. It's also very possible that the psychological effect of undergoing change in one's physical form could alter how one speaks/sings by various mechanisms (think gained/reduced confidence, or improved physical health making for a more efficient vocal mechanism, etc.).

So it could very well be the case that a person who loses a lot of weight might have their voice sound different than it used to, but unless the reduced mass could be traced back to a change in the vocal cords themselves, I don't think it could have the kind of effect that might transition a person from one natural voice type to another. Those kinds of factors are usually things like genetic influences on growth, changes in hormone balances, or medical side effects - none of which are usually easy to manipulate.

Answer (score 3):

Anecdotally, Maria Callas' voice went into slow decline after she shed a significant amount of weight in order to gain a better stage physique, presumably because of a change to her vocal support.

Again anecdotally, as a countertenor I have various things affecting the high reach of falsetto.

Bounceback items (good the day before, detrimental on the day itself): some kinds of exercise, (over-)eating, talking a lot, some beer.  Longterm bounceback (don't do on the day itself but keep a regimen): vocal range and support exercises, aerobic exercise.

Shortterm aids/superstitions: good hydration, chewing hot peppers (naturally not something you should try without being quite accustomed to its effects).

Combined with some superstition that kind of experience makes for a basis of rituals that may have some correlation to your vocal performance, possibly to some degree psychosomatic.

The problem with things like "drastic weight change" is that it is not something you can do often or short-term enough to get a solid impression of how it will affect your voice, and develop effective routines/superstition around it.

Also, low reach is directly related to dimensions of the larynx and, particularly at volume, the chest resonances, while high reach depends a lot on achievable closure.  While still related to larynx size, it's a lot less prescriptive.

In a nutshell: I wouldn't count on it, and it may or may not make a change for the better or worse.